# ES6 await on callback

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm about to write my first node.js app. I'm using a node module to download google font (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-font-installer).

The example code is based on

> .on('success', ...
>
> .on('error', ...

and I don't get it how to write it with await.

Thats is the example code from the package website:

```
var GoogleFontlist = require('google-font-installer');
 
var fontList = new GoogleFontlist('VALID_API_KEY');
 
fontList.on('success', function(){
    this.searchFontByName('Source Sans Pro', function(err, filteredList) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        filteredList.getFirst().download(['300', '400'], function(err, result){
            if (err)
                throw err;
            result.forEach(function(el, index){
                console.log('Variant %s of %s downloaded in %s', el.variant, el.family, el.path);
            })
        });
    })
})
 
fontList.on('error', function(err){
    throw err;
})
```

Any idea how to make it work, that my app is waiting for the download of the fonts with async-await or maybe promise when I wrap it in a download method in my class? I tested many different ways but I'm also not able to find any example like this.

Answer (score 1):

Callback-based API should be promisified, something like:

```
const fontListPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fontList = new GoogleFontlist('VALID_API_KEY');
    fontList.on('success', () => resolve(fontList));
    fontList.on('error', reject);
});
```

Then it can be used with promise API or with `async..await`:

```
const fontList = await fontListPromise;
fontList.searchFontByName(...);
```

`searchFontByName` can be promisified if needed, too.